# SVG icon only morphs once, won't morph back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm using [SVG Morpheus](https://github.com/alexk111/SVG-Morpheus) to morph two icons back and forth based on user clicks. I'm having two problems.

> 1) The first icon initially doesn't show up. I realize this is because
>   I put a `display:none` on there but that's how it was shown in the
>   demo. Am I supposed to take off the `display:none` styling for the initial icon?
>
> 2) When I first click on the 'Get in Touch' text, the icon morphs
>   fine. However, when I click the text (now 'Projects') again, the icon
>   doesn't morph back.

I've created two functions for the work icon to morph into the mail icon and vice-versa. Also, if there is a more efficient way of merging those two functions into one, I'm all ears.

Where have I gone wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8u9225q/5/

**HTML**

```
<div id="icons">
    <svg id="iconset" height="24" width="24" viewbox="0 0 24 24">
        <g id="work" style="display:none">
            <rect width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
            <rect x="8.7" width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
            <rect x="17.5" width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
            <rect y="8.7" width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
            <rect x="8.7" y="8.7" width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
            <rect x="17.5" y="8.7" width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
            <rect y="17.5" width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
            <rect x="8.7" y="17.5" width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
            <rect x="17.5" y="17.5" width="6.5" height="6.5"/>
        </g>
        <g id="mail" style="display:none">
            <polygon points="1.1,3.2 6.6,3.2 12.5,3.2 12,12.5"/>
            <polygon points="8.7,3.2 15.3,3.2 15.3,9.6 12,12.5"/>
            <polygon points="20.5,3.2 23,3.2 12,12.5 13.1,3.2"/>
            <polygon points="0,4.2 6.5,14.5 6.5,20.9 0,20.9"/>
            <rect x="8.7" y="14.5" width="6.5" height="6.4"/>
            <rect x="17.5" y="14.5" width="6.5" height="6.4"/>
            <polygon points="0,4.2 12,14.5 6.5,20.9 0,20.9"/>
            <rect x="6.3" y="14.5" width="11.4" height="6.4"/>
            <polygon points="12,14.5 24,4.2 24,20.9 17.5,20.9"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
<a id="contact-button" href="#">Get in touch</a>
```

**JS**

```
var c = 0;

function morphWork() {
    var myIcons = new SVGMorpheus('#iconset');
    myIcons.to('mail');
};

function morphMail() {
    var myIcons = new SVGMorpheus('#iconset');
    myIcons.to('work');
};

$('#contact-button').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (c++ % 2 == 0) {

        $(this).addClass('project-button').text('Projects');
        morphMail();

    } else {

        $(this).removeClass('project-button').text('Get in touch');
        morphWork();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Guess I could only use `var myIcons = new SVGMorpheus('#iconset');` once. This is the final result: http://jsfiddle.net/o8u9225q/6/

Answer (score -1):

Make your first icon `display:block;`. And instead of calling both function on one click make them different `click` function.

And to get mail icon you have to change your mail function.

```
 function morphWork() {
        var myIcons = new SVGMorpheus('#iconset');
        myIcons.to('mail');
    };

    function morphMail() {
        var myIcons = new SVGMorpheus('#iconset');
        myIcons.to('work');
    };
```

to this

```
   function morphWork() {
        var myIcons = new SVGMorpheus('#iconset');
        myIcons.to('work');
    };

    function morphMail() {
        var myIcons = new SVGMorpheus('#iconset');
        myIcons.to('mail');
    };
```